# Random crashes in platform views

Tags: android, crashlytics, crash-reports

Application was in production for about a 2 month and suddenly (without any application updates) I started receiving very weird crash-reports. I'm use Fabric to collect crash-reports. Screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

After a lot of research and googling (my code does nothing special with measuring) I don't know what can cause such crashes.

As I said above: exactly same apk was in production for 2 month without weird crashes.

Crashes happens on different devices, different manufactures, different android versions.

Some of them blows my mind with exception message like next:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 6
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.getAndVerifyPreorderedView(ViewGroup.java:3288)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2462)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2492)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2865)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2492)
...
```

And yes, I don't mess with touch events as well.

Another stack-trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: View with id 2131296529: android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout#onMeasure() did not set the measured dimension by calling setMeasuredDimension()
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22014)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6580)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22002)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:958)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
```

Anyone experienced such things? Ideas?

Comment: This question requires some attention.

Comment: same things happened to me. this weird exception made me crazy!